# Chained Python class invocations

Tags: python

I am trying to build a set of classes to define hierarchical properties for protocols in the OSI stack... in an abstract sense, I just need to inherit properties from parent python classes, but I need to be able to invoke the entire class chain at once... so, I'm looking for something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,fooprop1=None):
        return None
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self,barprop1=None):
        return None

if __name__=='__main__':
    tryit = Foo(fooprop1="someMacAddress").Bar(barprop1="someIpAddress")
```

However, invoking that script complains that `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'Bar'`

Can someone show me a way to get this done in python?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: It may not be the best idea to model the  OSI stack is as a class hierarchy.  The layers are completely independent of each other. Trying to do this by combining inheritance and delegation is probably a bad idea.  You might want to start again using just delegation.  Further, your example is a "fluent" interface, which is best done with delegation.

Comment: I agree with S.Lott!  Your OSI layers should be "Adapters", as the Design Pattern people call them, that are wrapped around each other and that rely on each other's interfaces.  You would them combine them with: `Bar("someIPAddress", Foo("someMacAddress"))` or, of course, could save the `foo` in a variable first if you needed independent access to it.

Comment: While it may seem that the OSI layers are completely independent, in reality they are not... for instance... a TCP PDU by itself means nothing... it is always wrapped inside an IP PDU, which is wrapped in an Ethernet (or PPP / HDLC) frame.  Ultimately, I want to be able to instantiate an IP stack, and then add TCP or UDP socket information on top of them... i.e.

<pre>
    host01 = Eth(macsrc="000a.dead.beef").IP(src="1.1.1.1",dst="100.10.10.5")
    socket01 = host01.TCP(srcport="1026",dstport="80")
    socket02 = host01.TCP(srcport.incr(),dstport="443")
</pre>
can delegation do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look how it is done in [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#stacking-layers):

```
$ sudo scapy
Welcome to Scapy (2.1.0) 
>>> sr(IP(dst="8.8.8.8") / UDP() / DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="stackoverflow.com")))
Begin emission:
..............................Finished to send 1 packets.
.............*
Received 44 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:1 ICMP:0 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>)
>>> ans = _[0]
>>> ans.summary()
IP / UDP / DNS Qry "stackoverflow.com"  ==> IP / UDP / DNS Ans "64.34.119.12"
```

`scapy` uses `/` operator to compose a packet from different layers.

Comment: Thank you, I wound up using a Python chain-of-responsibility pattern, based on code that leveraged __add__() to chain the responsible classes.  A simple implementation of that can be found in [Active State Recipe 302422](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302422-handler-stack/).  Essentially scapy is doing the same thing with __div__()

Answer (score 1):

As S.Lott mentions, you should be doing something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,fooprop1=None):
        return None

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,barprop1=None, afoo):
        self.foo = afoo
        return None

if __name__=='__main__':
    thefoo = Foo(fooprop1="someMacAddress")
    thebar = Bar(barprop1="someIpAddress", thefoo)
```